# Executar arquivo .SAS com DotNet

Tags: .net, integração, sas

Por gentileza, já precisaram fazer alguma integração SAS, executando o arquivo .sas e retornando o resultado com DotNet, via DataSet, String, etc.?

Se sim, qual objeto ou classe costuma-se a utilizar? Atualmente estou utilizando o SASIOM, fornecido pela própria SAS, mas não encontro nenhum método de execução para arquivos .sas, seja no Workspace, LanguageService ou FileService.

Muito obrigado desde já pela contribuição.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um artigo na própria comunidade SAS com um exemplo de utilização de arquivos .sas com .NET.

Segue o link do artigo:

https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/How-to-read-SAS-data-set-using-C-NET/td-p/168660

Caso dê algum erro com o link, segue um exemplo de utiização:

```
DataSet sasDs = new DataSet();
String sasLibrary = @"C\pasta_com_arquivo_sas\";

OleDbConnection connection= new OleDbConnection("Provider=sas.LocalProvider; Data Source=" + sasLibrary);
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd= connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
cmd.CommandText = "TableName"; 

//outra opção seria utilizar cmd.ExecuteReader();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(sasDs);

//sasDs deve conter o DataTable carregado nesse ponto.
//para filtrar os resultados, pode usar DataTable.Select()

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Otavio, muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda. Revirei tanta documentação... devo ter passado batido justo no que precisava, mas você ajudou demais! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @EdsonBassani, Tranquilo, que bom que ajudou! Se puder marcar como resposta da pergunta, ajudaria outras pessoas a identificarem. Valeu!